# How to prove that $a_{n} := \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)^2}$ converges to $2$ when $n\to\infty$ by the definition?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Just wondering if this is the correct way to approach and $\epsilon$ n proof for convergence.

I am starting with the sequence

$\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)^2}$

First step,
\begin{align*}
    \left|\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)^2} - 2 \right| 
    &= \left|\frac{(n+2)^{2}n^{2}+(n+1)^{4}-2(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2}} \right|< \epsilon\\
\end{align*}

since we have,

$(n+2)^{2}n^{2}+(n+1)^{4}-2(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2} < 2n^{4}(2n^{2}+4n+1)$

and,

$\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2}}< \frac{1}{n^{4}}$

so,

$
    \left|\frac{(n+2)^{2}n^{2}+(n+1)^{4}-2(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2}} \right|
    < \left|\frac{2n^{4}(2n^{2}+4n+1)}{n^{4}}\right|
    <2(2n^{2}+4n+1)\\[1em]
$
This is where I'm getting stuck: Solving we get,

$\frac{-\sqrt{\epsilon+2}-2}{2}<n<\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon +2}-2}{2}$

For any $\epsilon >0$. Does this make sense? Should I only be taking the positive value for epsilon?

Comment: I don't know where your upperbound $2n^{4}(2n^{2}+4n+1)$ comes from but it is far too gross. Find one which is of the size of $n^3$ instead of $n^6.$

Comment: This seems complicated to me, I would prove on the side that $\frac{n+a}{n+b}\to 1$ and then compose with square and sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

As a start, I would recommend you to split the argument into two parts. The first part corresponds to:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n^{2}}{(n + 1)^{2}} - 1 = -\frac{2n + 1}{(n + 1)^{2}} = \frac{1}{(n + 1)^{2}} - \frac{2}{n + 1}
\end{align*}
Similarly, the second part corresponds to:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(n + 1)^{2}}{(n + 2)^{2}} - 1 = -\frac{2n + 3}{(n + 2)^{2}} = \frac{1}{(n + 2)^{2}} - \frac{2}{n + 2}
\end{align*}
Letting $n\geq n_{\varepsilon}$, we arrive at the relation:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{n^{2}}{(n + 1)^{2}} + \frac{(n + 1)^{2}}{(n + 2)^{2}} - 2\right| & = \left|\frac{1}{(n + 1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n + 2)^{2}} - \frac{2}{n + 1} - \frac{2}{n + 2}\right|\\\\
& \leq \frac{1}{(n + 1)^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n + 2)^{2}} + \frac{2}{n + 1} + \frac{2}{n + 2}\\\\
& \leq \frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 2} + \frac{2}{n + 1} + \frac{2}{n + 2}\\\\
& \leq \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{n}\\\\
& = \frac{6}{n} \leq \frac{6}{n_{\varepsilon}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Partial fractions make it a lot easier to see what needs to happen. This then implies that $\forall n_{\epsilon} \in\mathbb{N}$ choosing $n_{\epsilon} >\frac{6}{\epsilon}$ should be sufficient as $\forall n \geq n_{\epsilon}$ we have $\frac{6}{n}<\epsilon$ as required?

Comment: The definition of convergence for sequences is given by:

$$(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |a_{n} - L| < \varepsilon)$$

Based on it, in the particular case that we are interested in, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ it suffices to take $n_{\varepsilon} = \lceil 6/\varepsilon\rceil$.